# Angular: Data not passing to child component after success call from parent

Tags: angular, typescript, button, parent-child, ngrx

I have a parent and child component.

In child component I have a button as below.

```
//child.component.html

<button mat-raised-button  [disabled]="!form.valid || submitButtonDisable" type = 'Submit' color='primary'  >
{{generateButton}}
</button>


//child.component.ts
@Output() onGenerateReport: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
@Input() generateButton: String;

OnSubmit() {
  this.onGenerateReport.emit(this.parameterRequest);  // paasing data to parent after button click
  this.submitButtonDisable = true;
  this.generateButton = 'Generating...'
  }
```

Below is the parent component

```
  // parent component.html

  <child-component
      (onGenerateReport)="handleGenerateReport($event)"
      [generateButton] = "generateButton | async">
  </child-component>

    //parent.component.ts
 generateButton: Observable<String >;

   handleGenerateReport($event: ParameterRequest) {  //  event trigerred

        this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.SendRequest($event));

    this.store.select(fromStore.isDataLoaded).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
    if(data) {
    this.generateButton = of('Generate');   // this data not passing to child
   }
 })
}
```

I am passing data to child after success call to change back the label of the button.

But ngrx select, **data not passing to child**.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ngOnChanges on a child to detect that change from parent.
You need to use below code in your child component.

```
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
class childComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit, AfterViewInit {    
//child.component.ts
@Output() onGenerateReport: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
@Input() generateButton: String;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void { 
  if(changes != null) {
    console.log(changes);   // here in changes object you will get the updated value of your input variables ex:  generateButton  
  }        
}

OnSubmit() {
   this.onGenerateReport.emit(this.parameterRequest);  // paasing data to parent after button click
   this.submitButtonDisable = true;
   this.generateButton = 'Generating...';}}
```

Comment: I am getting the value from the parent component, but weirdly it is not binding to the model in the html    `{{generateButton}}`

Comment: You need to reassign updated value to the var like this
this.generateButton = <updated value from changes> 
It would be great if you write your code so I understand what want wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just go through following steps

- Just import `import { Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';` package.
- Then implement interface `export class ComponentName implements OnChanges`
- Then just create function
  `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    // changes.your input property name (contains the old and the new value)
    // here you can getting all @Input property changes.
  }`